# Wordpress wp_editor to post and edit

Tags: posts, front-end, wp-editor

I browsed through all the topics here on stackexchange to find an answer to my problem but couldn't quite get there.

[This](http://snippi.com/s/pnm3un4) snippet enables you to post from the frontend, but how about editing. Each post on the front page should have a edit button, that leads to editing that post, so I should write some code to a loop I guess?

I'd like to be able to post and edit posts from the frontend kind of like in Facebook.
[example](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11912245/example.jpg)

Aaargh, it's driving me mad, I've tried to figure this out for weeks now. I have designed several sites with the WP but I wouldn’t consider my self as a coder, so ANY help would be greatly appreciated.

-Tuomas

Comment: http://vudu.me/2r8 I can point you to this series as a starting point. I'm not making this an answer, as I have not tested this out. BUt it is working for several folks. Hopefully it can at least get you started, until an answer comes along! (And I'm not sure how hard it would be to incorporate the editor into this)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you would have an Edit page and an Add New page, so why not just switch out the [`wp_insert_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) function from the Add New page to [`wp_update_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post)?

The first argument for [`wp_editor`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor) is the content you want to appear, so just use the current post that's being edited's content.